# Making two new variables with case_when or else if statement (R coding)

Tags: r, if-statement, group-by, dplyr, case-when

I need to make some changes to the data frame to be able to create a visual that I want, but I'm stuck. Down below is how the data frame looks like.
What I want to do is to make a new variable named 'article'. The values of this variable will be sum_pageviews of the 'Article Based' values from the 'Page' column.
Likewise, another variable will be 'info', and its values will be sum_pageviews from 'Informational Based' in Page variable.
Then the length of the data frame will be 8 in the end without the repetitiveness of department, and that's what I want to see.

[image]

Image down below is how new dataframe is supposed to be look like. I entered on Excel, but I'd like to know code in R.

[image]

--> I think I should start with

```
sum_views%>%group_by(department)%>%mutate
```

then ifelse or case_when statement, but no idea.
Please let me know the codes. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(article = case_when(str_detect(Page, 'Article Based') ~ sum_pageviews, TRUE ~ NA_real_), 
Info = case_when(str_detect(Page, 'Information Based') ~ sum_pageviews , TRUE ~ NA_real_)) %>% 
fill(article, .direction = 'down') %>% fill(Info, .direction = 'up') %>% select(-c(Page, sum_pageviews)) %>% 
group_by(department) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   department [5]
  department article  Info
  <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
1 Hess          1261  8443
2 Econ          2320 15682
3 DA            2495  7262
4 CS            5096  9870
5 Theatre       2992  5764
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   Page              department sum_pageviews
   <chr>             <chr>              <dbl>
 1 Article Based     Hess                1261
 2 Information Based Hess                8443
 3 Article Based     Econ                2320
 4 Information Based Econ               15682
 5 Article Based     DA                  2495
 6 Information Based DA                  7262
 7 Article Based     CS                  5096
 8 Information Based CS                  9870
 9 Article Based     Theatre             2992
10 Information Based Theatre             5764
```

Comment: Oh it works! Could you explain the code from the third line ( fill() ~~ ) for better understanding?

Comment: @hursooo, There'll be NA values for "Article Based" and "Information Based" under the new "Info" and "article" columns respectively, so the "fill" function fills those NA values with their respective columns values. Once the NA values are filled, we are selecting the first row from each "department" group.